# 'The type x exists in both dll' SAME dll + cast to CORRECT object type returns null?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, envdte, comobject

Some info: I'm using .Net 4.5, and trying to extend `Visual Studio 2013`.

This line of code works fine, I am getting an object

```
object vce = dte2.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt");
```

The type is, according to the watch window:
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt`
[image: vce type is VersionControlExt]

But, when I try to cast to this type by using this statement

```
VersionControlExt vceCast = vce as Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt;
```

I'm getting null
[image: vceCast is null]

### Weird part:

When I try to cast on watch window, I'm getting this **hilarious** error message:
[image: type exists in both]
`The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt' exists in both 
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll' and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll'`

As you can see - it's the **same** DLL!

I've tried to use `dynamic`, and then I got `RuntimeBinderInternalCompilerException An unexpected exception occurred while binding a dynamic operation`.

List of references I'm using:

[image]

### My conclusion:

I'm pretty sure that this is happening due to some bad references I've used. any  idea how to find them?

---

Side question: How can I iterate through COM Object like DTE/DTE2 to get info about a 'living' instance and it's properties?

Comment: You're referencing two different versions of Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll.  Don't do that.  You may have to use the fusion logger to determine who is picking up what version from where.  That's probably the best way to trace this out...

Comment: @Will, I've added references screenshot.

Comment: That's pointless.  The issue may lie in you referencing X which references version N while you reference version M directly.  Again, fusion logging is your friend in this.

Comment: The side question should be on a different post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For VS 2013 you need to reference version 12.0.0.0 of the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) of .NET Framework 4.x[image]:

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl\v4.0_12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll

And then the cast will be fine.

Comment: you are correct. I had reference to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl\v4.0_11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll` **Thanks**!